# gcov and unconditional loop coverage

Tags: c++, c, code-coverage, codecov

Does anyone know how gcov (for C and C++) handles conditional vs unconditional loops. Specifically, if you have a conditional loop, you need to test 0, 1 or more for the loop. If you have an unconditional loop, you do not need any additional tests. This is because an unconditional loop will always execute X number times no matter what the input to the loop is (think of a for loop that always starts at 0, and always ends a const value).

The question is, how does gcov (and the associated reporting tools) handle this. If a loop is unconditional, there is no way to test for 0, 1, or more. Do these tools take this into account so that your total % of code coverage is not negatively impacted?

Comment: I don't understand. gcov just counts how many times source lines were executed. What difference does it make if loops are "conditional" or "unconditional" (whatever that means)?

Comment: @FredLarson: There is also branch coverage, but OP's definition of (un)conditional loop seems unrelated to coverage.

Comment: For me `while (true){ /*..*/}` is unconditional loop (with unconditional jump (even if compiler might generate unneeded branch, which would indeed might have negative impact for coverage tool)). `for (int i = 0; i != 42; ++i)` has conditional branch, and both branches are covered in regular run (no `break`). 0, 1, 2+ runs seems more related to path or decision coverage.

Comment: @Jarod42 This might help for reference: https://partiu.loggi.com/road-to-100-coverage-conditions-and-loops-33069ce5be72

Comment: @FredLarson, See the link in the comment above, but if gcov is only counting the number of times a line is executed, I wonder how tools like CodeCov measure loop and branch conditionals. I feel like there has to be more information there as they need to tell the difference between MC/DC branches as well, which you cannot get from a simple line count.

Comment: Please provide a [example], showing the loop to check, listing the cases you like to test, and telling us the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There are different type of coverage used by tool, including

- line coverage
- statement coverage
- branch/decision coverage

for `f1(); if (a || b) { f2(); } f3();`

we have:

- 1 line
- 5 statements (`a`, `b`, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`)
- 4 branches (`a==(true|false)`, `b==(true|false)` -> 2 + 2)
- 3 paths (`{a, b}=={true, _}`, `{a, b}=={false, false}`, `{a, b}=={false, true}`)

No real relations between those metrics

One run will test one path, and any number of the other metrics.

Your unconditional loop (as `for (int i : {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42})`) will indeed not increase number of paths, will increase branch count by one, and increase statements count. But any path taking that unconditional loop will cover all statements and branches of your unconditional loop.

Your conditional loop (`for (int i : my_numbers)`) will increase branch count by one, might increase number of path (emptiness of container by already be fixed by the previous step of the path) and increase statement count.
If you run a path using non-empty container, you will cover all statements and branches, but indeed not necessary all paths.

Most tools doesn't use path coverage (as it grows too much to be usable)

and conditional vs unconditional loop only matters for that metrics.